# Wordpress and Bootstrap Not Responsive

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Good day, 
I'm having a bit of a problem getting Bootstrap to function with Wordpress. My current theme is working wonderfully, and as I try to implement Bootstrap, it isn't picking up the responsiveness... But it centers the container! 
Anyway I'll break the files down and try to make them as simple as I can to follow.

**Header.php**

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-md-12">
                <header role="banner">
                  Header related wp code. 
                </header>

        </div>
  </div>
```

**Page.php**

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
  body related wp code
</div>


<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**Sidebar.php**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <aside>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 
            labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
            laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in 
            voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat 
            non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

    </aside>
</div>
</div> <!-- End .row -->
```

**footer**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
  <footer>
      Footer related wp code here. 
        </p>

       </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- end of .container -->
```

I'm not a noob with Bootstrap, but nothing inside of the rows or column spans is positioning itself properly; it's one linear workspace. the content also does not fix itself to fit when I open it on my tablet. 
Am I doing anything wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some classes for Tablet and mobiles.

You are using only col-md-6

Example: Mobile, tablet, desktops

Build on the previous example by creating even more dynamic and powerful layouts with tablet .col-sm-* classes.

Source: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Check Example for Mobile,Tablets and Desktops.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
  <!-- Optional: clear the XS cols if their content doesn't match in height -->
  <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wordpress with some different theme and template
Find out the **boostrap.css** is loading or not.

you can check using a view source and search for the code bootstrap.css

in my case it was coming with htbbootstrap.css if it is coming then go inside and search for the **col-lg**

You can see here all boostrap classes prefix with some other text

for example

**col-lg comes with htb-col-lg**

**col-md comes with htb-col-md**

and so on.